# Установка темы из репозитория Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, веб-программирование

Я сделал следующие действия:

1. Создал папку C:\OSPanel\domains\myfirstwpsite.ru;
2. Скопировал содержимое архива wordpress-5.8.2-ru_RU.zip, взятого с https://ru.wordpress.org/download/ (из папки wordpress этого архива) в папку C:\OSPanel\domains\myfirstwpsite.ru;
3. Создал в рhpMyAdmin базу myfirstwpsite;
4. Открыл в браузере адрес myfirstwpsite.ru;
5. Сделал 5-минутную установку.

   В результате получил сайт с темой Twenty Twenty-One

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

который имеет следующий вид

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

6. Добавил новую тему Newses

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(плагин shortbuild установил)

7. После щелчка на ссылке Настроить (в правом нижнем углу темы) открывается страница сайта

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно из скриншотов произошла склейка старой темы Twenty Twenty-One с новой - Newses. Как избавиться от содержимого из Twenty Twenty-One в Newses?
Подскажите что и в каких файлах надо изменить (или может быть нужно что-то поменять в админке).

Comment: Это не склейка темы. После установки WordPress по-умолчанию имеет некоторый контент, такой как запись "Привет, мир!", это никоим образом не зависит от темы. Хотите удалить запись, перейдите в записи и удалите, в чем проблема? Активация другой темы, не меняет контент на сайте. Все это меняется в админ панели. Прежде чем заниматься разработкой, ознакомьтесь с тем, как работает стандартный функционал этой CMS.

Comment: @Simon я вставил рисунок с темой (2-й скриншот) и на ней видно, что есть элементы Поиск, Свежие записи, Свежие комментарии, Архивы и Рубрики. Они берутся из темы Twenty Twenty-One (темы по умолчанию) и используются в теме Newses. Как избавиться от этого содержимого в Newses?

Comment: Внешний вид -> Виджеты