# Записи в wordpress теме Newses

Tags: php, html, wordpress, веб-программирование

Скачал тему Newses из Wordpress репозитория (см. [Установка wordpress темы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1359009/%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F-wordpress)). В ней 4 раза выводится одна и та же запись Привет, мир!.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В каком из файлов шаблона происходит вывод записей на экран?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните или переформулируйте вопрос.

Comment: Если я вас правильно понимаю, то вы хотите избавится от 4 записей привет мир?

Comment: @ИванИпатов Я хочу вывести свои посты вместо записей Привет, мир!. Для этого я должен знать где происходит вывод постов.

Comment: Вы уже создали ваши посты?

Comment: @ИванИпатов Нет пока что. Я просто спрашиваю, где происходит вывод текущих постов (в файлах шаблона Newses).

Comment: Как только вы добавите свои записи они автоматически появятся на главной странице и в сопутствующих рубриках, настраивать это необязательно, а привет мир просто удалите